# How to add a file to IPFS using the API?

Tags: ipfs, api-design

I have tried some APIs of IPFS like cat, ls. But I am not able to add the file using API. As there is no proper documentation of IPFS API calls.

How can I add a file on IPFS using API?

Comment: FYI, Off-topic discussion of this question at [meta](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/290/87).

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, someone solved?

Answer (score 17):

Read the [documentation](https://ipfs.io/docs/api/):

> Every command usable from the cli is also available through the HTTP
> API. For example:
>
> ipfs swarm peers
>
> curl http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/swarm/peers

So for the command:

> USAGE   ipfs add ... - Add a file to ipfs.
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> < path >... - The path to a file to be added to IPFS.

https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-add

the equivalent API call would be:

```
curl -F "image=@/home/bar.jpg" 127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add
```

---

If you want to use a webpage to upload a document into ipfs it should be something like

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to upload a file from html page to ipfs using ipfs api. Please guide me from that point of view. @Roland

Comment: aniket added it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll make sure its correctness after implementing it. :)

Comment: *File argument 'path' is required* getting this error after executing your html code @Roland, URL is like api/v0/add?image=imagename.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to change name="image" to "path"?

Comment: yeah, i tried. Now it still shows same error with replacement of 'path' to 'image' in url

Comment: Even above given the equivalent API (curl -F ...) is also not working using terminal. @Roland

Comment: this progress flag thing might be the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580093/ipfs-add-returns-2-jsons

Comment: while running that api command, it just shows me an error that it is unable to find that file....and i have added that same file using normal command @Roland

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40698/discussion-between-aniket-and-roland-kofler).

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new answer as it is rather unrelated from the previous one.

**Massive thanks to [Vaibhav Saini](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/29956/vaibhav-saini) who was supporting me on GitHub and [IPFS forum](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-there-any-other-methods-to-upload-a-file-files-to-ipfs-through-a-web-browser-beside-using-api-port-5001/3143/10?u=mars).**

It's relatively simple, of course you can simplify even further by removing jQuery, here used only as `on change input type file` handler:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Infura IPFS CORS issue</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-http-client@30.1.3/dist/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://bundle.run/buffer@5.2.1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>readAsArrayBuffer to Buffer to Infura to IPFS</h3>

    <input type="file" id="upload">

    <div id="link"></div> <!-- markup created after upload -->

    <script>
        const ipfs = window.IpfsHttpClient('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', { protocol: 'https' });

        $("#upload").on("change", function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {

                const magic_array_buffer_converted_to_buffer = buffer.Buffer(reader.result); // honestly as a web developer I do not fully appreciate the difference between buffer and arrayBuffer 
                ipfs.add(magic_array_buffer_converted_to_buffer, (err, result) => {
                    console.log(err, result);

              let ipfsLink = "<a href='https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/" + result[0].hash + "'>gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/" + result[0].hash + "</a>";
              document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = ipfsLink;

                })
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
        })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: https://github.com/linonetwo/ipfs-uploader-browser

```
export default class FileUploadInput extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    readAs: PropTypes.oneOf(['readAsDataURL', 'readAsArrayBuffer', 'readAsBinaryString', 'readAsText']),
    onReadSuccess: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onReadFailure: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    allowMultiple: PropTypes.bool,
    validateFiles: PropTypes.func,
    initialText: PropTypes.string,
    inputProps: PropTypes.object,
    fileInputProps: PropTypes.object,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    readAs: 'readAsArrayBuffer',
    allowMultiple: false,
    validateFiles: files => null,
    initialText: '',
    inputProps: {},
    fileInputProps: {},
  };

  node: any;
  stream: any;

  state = {
    progress: 0,
    totalFileSize: 0,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: props.initialText, files: [] };

    // use random repo to initialize ipfs
    const repoPath = 'ipfs-' + Math.random();
    this.node = new IPFS({ repo: repoPath });

    // 'ready' will trigger after ipfs has start connecting to other peer
    this.node.on('ready', () => console.log('Online status: ', this.node.isOnline() ? 'online' : 'offline'));
  }

  /** 3.put file into IPFS */
  uploadIPFS = (fileArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer): Promise<Buffer> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // set progress
      this.setState({ progress: 0 });
      // create stream that used to change progress
      const myReadableStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer({
        chunkSize: 25000,
      });
      // set progress
      myReadableStreamBuffer.on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
        this.setState({ progress: this.state.progress + chunk.byteLength });
        myReadableStreamBuffer.resume();
      });


      this.stream = this.node.files.addReadableStream();
      // resolve after file has uploaded
      this.stream.on('data', (file: Buffer) => resolve(file));

      // put file stream into IPFS's stream
      this.stream.write(myReadableStreamBuffer);
      myReadableStreamBuffer.put(Buffer.from(fileArrayBuffer));

      // close it after uploading
      myReadableStreamBuffer.on('end', () => this.stream.end());
      myReadableStreamBuffer.stop();
    });
  };

  /** 2.prepare file for IPFS uploading */
  readFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = event => resolve(this.uploadIPFS(event.target.result));
      fileReader.onerror = reject;
      fileReader[this.props.readAs](file);
    });
  }

  /** clear display */
  resetState() {
    this.setState({ text: '', files: [] });
  }

  /** 1.get file from <input/> */
  async handleChange(event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) {
    // dealwith errors
    const files: File[] = Array.from(event.target.files);
    if (!files.length) {
      return this.resetState();
    }
    const errMsg = this.props.validateFiles(files);
    if (errMsg) {
      this.resetState();
      return this.props.onReadFailure(errMsg);
    }

    // update display
    const text = files.length > 1 ? `${files.length} files...` : files[0].name;
    this.setState({ text, files });

    // set progress's total size
    let totalFileSize = 0;
    files.forEach(file => {
      totalFileSize += file.size;
    });
    this.setState({ totalFileSize });
    // put file
    try {
      const response = await Promise.all([...files.map(aFile => this.readFile(aFile))]);
      this.props.onReadSuccess(response);
    } catch (err) {
      this.resetState();
      this.props.onReadFailure(err.message);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span className={this.props.className}>
        {/* input used for display */}
        <input
          placeholder={this.props.allowMultiple ? 'Select files' : 'Select a file'}
          value={this.state.text}
          readOnly
          onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}
          {...this.props.inputProps}
        />
        {/* input used for upload */}
        <input
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          ref={el => (this.fileInput = el)}
          type="file"
          multiple={this.props.allowMultiple}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          {...this.props.fileInputProps}
        />
        <ProgressBar progress={this.state.progress} total={this.state.totalFileSize} />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code from: https://github.com/cluster-labs/ipfscloud-web#how-to-use

Proof that it was working once: https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXhpBNwxEuXuuyKEpYouNvSZw2MqRemtUNSWKbKEiuhBv

**But cannot 100% reliably vouch for it.**

*(credit for simplicity)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IpfsCloud demo</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vasa-develop/ipfscloud@f157536445863f27481d8ce5e3025f25264d1113/app/docs/v1/css/ipfscloud-uploader.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <center>
        <div id="IpfsCloudUploader"></div>
        <div id="IpfsGatewayUploadedLink"></div>
    </center>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vasa-develop/ipfscloud@bd23078768a5c708fc0f322a3e0e0cfb45b61f71/app/docs/v1/js/ipfscloud-uploader.min.js" ></script>

    <script>
    ipfscloud.addEventListener("icevent", function(event) {

        console.log(event.detail);

        if (event.detail.status === "success") {
            let ipfsLink = "https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/" + event.detail.data.path;
            document.getElementById("IpfsGatewayUploadedLink").innerHTML = ipfsLink;

        } else {
            console.log(event.detail);
            alert("something happened, check console");
        }
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** it is workign now, see [this issue](https://github.com/cluster-labs/ipfscloud-web/issues/20#issuecomment-486390568)

Comment: I added a new dedicated node for ipfscloud. Now you can rely on it ;)

Comment: @VaibhavSaini thank you for all the help and support. Trust (and reliability) is something you build for years, and then one moment is gone. For my needs I'll probably use Infura (backed by Consensys). They have unlimited resources. Among other news - happy to work together, you have loads of potential 